# How to separate sting with comma plus 8 digits

Tags: c#, string

I want to split a long string (that contains only numbers) to string arr 0f numbers with 8 digits after the comma.

for example:

input:

```
string str = "45.00019821162.206580920.032150970.03215097244.0031982274.245303020.014716900.046867870.000198351974.613444580.391664580.438532450.00020199 3499.19734739 0.706802871.145335320.000202002543.362378010.513759201.659094520.000202102.391733720.000483371.65957789"
```

output:

```
string[] Arr=
" 
45.00019821 162.20658092 234.03215097 123123.03215097
255.00019822 74.24530302 23422.01471690 1.04686787
12.00019835 1974.61344458 234.39166458 123212.43853245
532.00020199 3499.19734739 878.70680287 1.14533532
1234.00020200 2543.36237801 23.51375920 1.65909452
12221.00020210 2.39173372 0.00048337 1.65957789"
```

EDIT:

I try use

```
String.Format("{0:0.00000000}", str);
```

or some SubString such as:

```
public static string GetSubstring(string input, int count, char delimiter) 
{ 
    return string.Join(delimiter.ToString(), input.Split(delimiter).Take(count)); 
}
```

with no success.

Comment: And what is stopping you? Haven't you tried anything?

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. People here expect from you that you at least **try** to solve this problem on your own. Please don't post simply requirements and expect others to do your job

Comment: _"long string (that contains only numbers)"_ - if you talking about `str`, there are not only numbers.

Comment: I try use  String.Format("{0:0.00000000}", str); or some SubString suce as public static string GetSubstring(string input, int count, char delimiter)
        {
            return string.Join(delimiter.ToString(),
                               input.Split(delimiter).Take(count));
        } with no success..

Comment: @SeM You may be thinking of *digits*.

Comment: @SeM: From the point of view that "0.1234" is a number it does contain only numbers. I think the point is that there are no delimiters.

Comment: I often advise against regex, but: https://regex101.com/r/Q9UXhv/1 ?

Comment: @Fildor: Post that as an answer not as a comment...

Comment: @Chris Point taken ... writing.

Comment: @Chris Well yeah, it will contain only numbers if there was a kind of separator (space or something, because there is no number such as .0.123.234.345.) and there will be only numbers if he split that string the way he wants.

Comment: @SeM: I'm not sure what point you're making. Perhaps you should edit the question if you feel you have better wording.

Comment: richej was faster ... I was still writing on this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZBsaBC

Answer (score 4):

You can split the string using Regex:

```
var strRegex = @"(?<num>\d+\.\d{8})";
var myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(str))
{
    var part = myMatch.Groups["num"].Value;

    // convert 'part' to double and store it wherever you want...
}
```

**More compact version:**

```
var myRegex = new Regex(@"(?<num>\d*\.\d{8})", RegexOptions.None);

var myNumbers = myRegex.Matches(str).Cast<Match>()
      .Select(m => m.Groups["num"].Value)
      .Select(v => Convert.ToDouble(v, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: You beat me to it; nice one.  Only comment; `var part` would be overwritten each time, so it may be worth tweaking your example to use `Console.WriteLine` / `yield return` / `result.Add`, or something like that; just to show that each returned part is important.

Comment: Thanks ! i will test it now.

Comment: You were faster ... was writing on a similar answer. Only thing: I'd make that `\d+` instead of `\d*`.

Answer (score 1):

This would be the classical for-loop version of it, (no magic involved):

```
// split by separator 
string[] allparts = str.Split('.');
// Container for the resulting numbers
List<string> numbers = new List<string>();
// Handle the first number separately
string start = allparts[0];
string decimalPart ="";

for (int i = 1; i < allparts.Length; i++)
{       
    decimalPart = allparts[i].Substring(0, 8);
    numbers.Add(start + "." + decimalPart);
    // overwrite the start with the next number
    start = allparts[i].Substring(8, allparts[i].Length - 8);
}
```

EDIT:

Here would be a LINQ Version yielding the same result:

```
// split by separator 
string[] allparts = str.Split('.');

IEnumerable<string> allInteger = allparts.Select(x => x.Length > 8 ? x.Substring(8, x.Length - 8) : x);
IEnumerable<string> allDecimals = allparts.Skip(1).Select(x => x.Substring(0,8));

string [] allWholeNumbers = allInteger.Zip(allDecimals, (i, d) => i + "." + d).ToArray();
```

Comment: On your last substring you can just do Substring(8) without having to do that length calculation. Looks a bit neater if you ask me (though it is a purely subjective thing).

Comment: @Chris you are right. But I think I favor readability here before calculation cost

Answer (score 1):

The input string `str` can be converted to the desired output as follows.

```
static IEnumerable<string> NumberParts(string iString)
 {
     IEnumerable<char> iSeq = iString;
     while (iSeq.Count() > 0)
     {
         var Result = new String(iSeq.TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
         iSeq = iSeq.SkipWhile(Char.IsDigit);
         Result += new String(iSeq.Take(1).ToArray());
         iSeq = iSeq.Skip(1);
         Result += new String(iSeq.Take(8).ToArray());
         iSeq = iSeq.Skip(8);
         yield return Result;
     }
 }
```

The parsing method above can be called as follows.

```
var Parts = NumberParts(str).ToArray();
var Result = String.Join(" ", Parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way without regex:

```
var splitted = ("00000000" + str.Replace(" ", "")).Split('.');

var result = splitted 
    .Zip(splitted.Skip(1), (f, s) => 
        string.Concat(f.Skip(8).Concat(".").Concat(s.Take(8))))
    .ToList()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZBPa8MwDMXv/RTGl9qsE7Llv5TustvYaR0MdgtZOkJLW5JsXz@Tk7TTITwrv/ckVPePdd@O42/ViX7oxE5I5wERTU7WmGDBYvAJs0VAssZjjv/KOscsFdZGB9Z5QsKCGhdNyMjKhRRiKqYplLzJjAZDzjkOBsomhEk5Sp44Y0Itw1mQyxnYQC5SFggRQ0KbogHDs4jxBbb88Y6AgqWY0CB4Q9Hz2gaCz5idv6MGbZkaieLcc4nlxPkYU5bb1Wq6x/XUDkPzxUdREpeS4qEcCt6a66mqGyWF3AgptYZ9wdUa1nrxd03/cxrYfQ9aCS74bK/q1oL9kV9Gb4Q6bESvxe5ppkrxnPb8Dc@Xc10N6jCzSd8aEuRd9/BeHRv@yTVPeb@8tv2gyjIfXTs0akl7ubRnJbdl7XlBrbfj@Ac)